# Change the Query String Content edit or split from web config file (QUERY_STRING server variable)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem regarding a ISAPI rule in the web.config file. I want to change the content of a query string. That means I want to split the query string so I can remove the undesired data before writing it back to URL.

```
<rule name="something">
 <matchurl=".?" />
  <condition logicalgrouping="matchall">
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern={something2} />
  </condition>
  <action type="redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}QUERYSTRING"appendQueryString="True" redirecttype="found" />
```

Now I want to remove some part of the querystring. How can I do that? Does anybody know how to split or edit the contents of the querystring?

Comment: Why don't you change the query string content as you retrieve it from the URL? Or as you construct it?

Comment: Yeah i want that i want to change the content of the query string where i just want to remove one part from it but i have to do it in web.config file i do not have permissions to do it in from any other file like .cs or java script if you any thing which could do the same write the code

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UriBuilder` and `HttpUtility` to do this. First drop the URL into the `UriBuilder`:

```
var uri = new UriBuilder(url);
uri.Port = -1;
```

now work with the query string:

```
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
```

then remove the ones you don't want:

```
query.Remove("parmName");
```

and then put it back together:

```
uri.Query = query.ToString();
var newUrl = uri.ToString();
```

Comment: I have to do this in the web.config file it self not on .cs file or js aur any where else i have to do it on the webconfig file it self                             Thanks